# What's a a tuple variant? (understanding compiler error message)

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

Using `wasm_bindgen` with `serde`, I'm trying to return a `JsValue` for a complex structure using idiomatic rust.  I've created an isolated example to illustrate the error that I'm seeing.

struct declaration:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct BookStoreData {
    pub h: HashMap<String, String>,
    pub name: String,
}
```

function definition:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn hello_hash(count: i32) -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    set_panic_hook();
    let mut book_reviews = HashMap::new();

    book_reviews.insert(
        "Grimms' Fairy Tales".to_string(),
        "Masterpiece.".to_string(),
    );
    let data = BookStoreData {
        h: book_reviews,
        name: "My Book Store".to_string(),
    };

    let js_result: JsValue = JsValue::from_serde(&data).unwrap();

    OK(js_result)    

}
```

I get this compilation error:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `OK` in this scope
  --> src/hello_whatever.rs:46:5
   |
46 |     OK(js_result)    
   |     ^^ help: a tuple variant with a similar name exists: `Ok`
```

You can see the[full example](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/hello-rust-parcel/tree/ok-error) based on [rust-parcel-template](https://github.com/rustwasm/rust-parcel-template)

To reproduce the the error, from the root of the repo, run `npm run start` or `cd crate && cargo build`

Comment: Use `Ok` instead of `OK` small `k`

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't see it.  The help message should have been helpful. I just kept re-reading it and wondering how Ok could have multiple tuple variants, and missed the capitalization difference.  Thank you @sn99 !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the answer was provided as a comment.  `Ok` is spelled with lower-case `k` but it didn't explain the meaning of error message.

First, here is the working code with that one small change:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn hello_hash(count: i32) -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    set_panic_hook();
    let mut book_reviews = HashMap::new();

    book_reviews.insert(
        "Grimms' Fairy Tales".to_string(),
        "Masterpiece.".to_string(),
    );
    let data = BookStoreData {
        h: book_reviews,
        name: "My Book Store".to_string(),
    };

    let js_result: JsValue = JsValue::from_serde(&data).unwrap();

    Ok(js_result)    

}
```

Second, what's a tuple variant?

In this context, the line in question could be a function or a *tuple variant* of a struct or an enum (via [tweet](https://twitter.com/ekuber/status/1183410450123255808) by friendly Rustacean):

tuples can be used in a struct or an enum:

```
struct S(usize); // tuple-like struct
enum E {
    T(usize), // tuple variant
}
```

More detail in blog post: [What's a tuple variant?](https://www.ultrasaurus.com/2019/10/rust-whats-a-tuple-variant/)

This particular confusing error message may be improved in the future.  Blog post and subsequent [twitter discussion](https://twitter.com/ultrasaurus/status/1183402662340907008) led to this error report: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65386